# Js code always runs even i don't hit the button

Tags: javascript

I have a js code and I wanna run it when I click the button.It's seems ok to me but it's run even i don't hit the button.

Probably it has a simple answer but I couldn't handle it.I'm new....

```js
var upgradeTime = 600;
var seconds = upgradeTime;

function timer() {
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 
        days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Tamamlandı.";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>

<input id="" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="timer();" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);`
 outside the function:

1. You can include all your core logic to a new function `coreTimer()`
2. Call `coreTimer()` from `timer()`
3. make sure `countdownTimer` is declared in global scope so that it can be cleared using `clearInterval` inside `coreTimer()` function.

```js
var upgradeTime = 10;
var seconds = upgradeTime;
var countdownTimer;
function timer() {
   countdownTimer = setInterval('coreTimer()', 1000);
}

function coreTimer() {
  var days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60);
  var hoursLeft = Math.floor((seconds) - (days * 86400));
  var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
  var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
  var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
  }
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Tamamlandı.";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>

<input id="" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="timer();" />
```

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes, you are correct. Agree with you. we need `countdownTimer` on global scope. Updated!!

Comment: just saw that, and therefore removed my comment as it was no longer relevant :)

Comment: Thank you it works perfect! Now I learned call a function in a function too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals. So the statement

```
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

will execute your timer function every 1000 milliseconds. Hence your function is getting called even when you are not clicking the button. You need to modify that statement accordingly or remove it completely.